# Android Studio cannot enable chackbox programmatically

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-view, android-checkbox

I successfully added my customView programatically in my LinearLayout. Now I want to check the checkbox by position. This is my code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/recycler_view_item_height"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/polygon_name"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:gravity="center|left"
 android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
 android:maxLines="1"
 android:singleLine="true"
 android:textColor="#4d4d4d"
 android:textSize="16dp"
 android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/vin_code"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#4d4d4d"
    android:textSize="16dp"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Java code:

```
 final int childcount = linearLayout.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < childcount; i++) {
                View view = linearLayout.getChildAt(i);
                if (i == selectedPosition) {
                    LinearLayout mmLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) view;
                    for (int j = 0; j < mmLinearLayout.getChildCount(); j++) {
                        View mview = mmLinearLayout.getChildAt(i);
                        if (mview instanceof CheckBox)
                            ((CheckBox) mview).setChecked(true);

                    }



                    view.setBackgroundColor(activeColor);
                }
            }
```

I debuged my code and my instanceOf working but I can't check the checkbox programmatically.
How can I solve this problem? Thanks everyone

Comment: your checkbox is not a child of your linearlayout. give it an id and use findViewById instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
((CheckBox) view).setChecked(true);
```

instead of

```
((CheckBox) view).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

to check the checkbox.